# Error: "api-ms-win-crt-string-|l1-1-0.dll missing from your computer " while installing NLTK

Tags: nltk

I have already tried uninstalling and reinsalling Visual C++ Redistributable and also installed all windows updates.But the problem still persists.Please help

Comment: NLTK works on Python, not C++ ;P

Comment: @alvas I know,but when I was looking for the soultions to fix the dll error,one of the suggestions was to have visual c++ installed and windows properly updated. I